# After I installed Ubuntu on SSD Fedora in NVME on no longer available

Tags: 20.04, grub2, ssd, boot-repair, nvme

I have NVME and SSD both on my PC. I installed and used Fedora on NVME, but I decided to switch to Ubuntu and installed it on SSD, leaving Fedora untouched. However, GRUB only sees SSD with Ubuntu now.

I used command

```
sudo apt install btrfs-progs -y
```

And now GParted sees /dev/nvme0n1p1 and /dev/nvme0n1p2 (where Fedora is installed), but that's not much help cause I can't see it in file manager, and also Boot Repair (which I used as LiveUSB) didn't help. Only GParted sees /dev/nvme0n1p2 but not Boot Repair or Ubuntu itself.

BootInfo Summary

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7kVQ3gP4rc/

And I need to use BOTH Fedora on nvme and Ubuntu on ssd

Comment: With UEFI and especially NVMe drives, installing any OS in Legacy mode (and MBR) is a huge mistake.

Comment: You mean I may not be able to recover the information completely?

Comment: You should be able to recover any non-encrypted data if using a Fedora live/installation media, that wasn't the point of my comment nor is it in the question itself. I was merely pointing out the problems you created for yourself by (1) using MBR and (2) apparently installing Fedora in Legacy mode. You need to understand the differences, understand why UEFI is the standard for the last 10 years and understand how to manage bootloaders from the firmware (UEFI) when properly installed (UEFI mode) or how to change drives' boot order when installed in Legacy mode. (...)

Comment: (...) Other than that I can't help you. To be honest I don't even understand how it ended up in such mess, going by the Boot Repair summary. Others with more expertise than me might help. That said this is mostly a Fedora issue according to your comment.

Comment: Report does show p1 & p2, but not any kernel for Fedora? Did you  have another boot partition on sda that now is overwritten?